# How to make my Excel worksheet pull certain cell values for File name when I Save As?

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, I will try to explain this the best I can. I have an Excel workbook that will be used as a cost sheet. At the top of this worksheet will be a Proposal Number (in cell D3), Customer Name in cell D4), and System Size (in cell D5). So let's say my sheet is Proposal Number 4423 for Customer Shanghai Noon and System Size 2500. I would like when I click Save As for it to automatically name the file "4423 Shanghai Noon SCR-2500 Tsoc". Is there a way to do this with a Macro or any other way? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Ok so this is the code I got from recording a macro but it keeps saying Compile error: Expected: end of statement. I don't know how to make it use the text from these cells in the Save As.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\walkerja\Documents\CU Proposals\Range("D3").Select Range("D4").Select SCR-Range("D5").Select Tsoc.xlsm", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: yes there is, just record selecting the cells, and saving the workbook, and you will have the bare bones code which you can work with and we'll help you

Comment: Agree with @Philip here. You will have to record a macro and then amend it to suit your needs and if then you are stuck simply post the code that you tried and the error message that you are getting (if any) we will take it from there.

Comment: Hey guys, I have posted the code I got but it isn't working. Any advice or alterations would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
Dim part1 As String
Dim part2 as String
Dim part3 as String

part1 = Range("D3").Value
part2 = Range("D4").Value
part3 = Range("D5").Value

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"C:\Users\walkerja\Documents\CU Proposals\" & part1 & " " & part2 & " SCR-" & part3 & " Tsoc.xlsm", FileFormat:= _
xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

You were mixing string values with spreadsheet operation methods.  You need to get the values of your cells first, then you can use those values to build a string for the file name.

Comment: Thanks Stewbob. This works great. I am running into one problem though. I put this in a Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave. Would this be the best place or should I just make a macro button for it? Because in my code it is telling it to save so I am actually saving it twice so when I Save As it is saying a file already exists. Also, when I just do a quick save my workbook just shuts down. How could I fix this?

Comment: A separate button is probably the easiest to implement, but really you could go either way.  If you put it in `Workbook_BeforeSave` you will need to do a little research to figure out how to pass your filename to Excel so that you don't save it twice.

Comment: Alright, I'll probably go with the button to avoid any complications and. Thanks again!